# Why does this return zero results?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, c#-4.0

I have a `List<List<string>>` and when I try to search with the `List<string>` it returns no results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
        List<List<string>> test = new List<List<string>>();

        List<string> ff = new List<string>();
        ff.Add("1");
        ff.Add("ABC 1");
        test.Add(ff);

        ff = new List<string>();
        ff.Add("2");
        ff.Add("ABC 2");

        test.Add(ff);

        var result = test.Where(x=>x.Contains("ABC"));

        //result.Count(); is 0
```

Comment: Likely you meant `test.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("ABC"));`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither of your lists contains the element "ABC".

If you want to find the lists that have an element that contains "ABC" as a substring you can do this:

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Contains("ABC")));
```

Comment: To make it work, one would have to override the Contains() method of `List<string>` to search within each string and just equal to each string, which could be slow.

Comment: This works but I dont understand how because Any() just returns a bool

Comment: The Any is a predicate on the select. It's the same as saying "Select where Y = ABC". You wouldnt expect your select to not work because your where clause deals with booleans.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make it case-insensitive?

Comment: @Jon: See this question for case-insensitive `string.Contains`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 0):

none of your lists contain the string "ABC". It doesn't search the string when you use that contains function, it just matches the whole string. If you want to search for a partial string, then you have to use something like the following:

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.Where(y => y.Contains("ABC").Count() > 0));
```

Comment: I changed it so it should return a `List<List<string>>` of the items that you want

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are doing a list of a list and not going far enough down in your selection. Something like this should give you two results:

```
var result = test.Select(x => x.Where(y => y.Contains("ABC")));
```

Comment: Almost but I need the result to be a List<List<string>>